# App crashes when loading Phone contacts with images in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My Windows phone 8.1 application is on store now. Nowadays we are getting app crash issues from some users that the app is crashing when he navigating in to a page which loading all phone book contacts with images.

Checked with the Windows Dev center Dashboard and found a related exception. We are not able to reproduce this type of exception on our end since it is difficult to solve thus issue.

> CLR_EXCEPTION_System.Exception_80131500_Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.UserData.PhoneDataSharingContext.MapHrToException

**Stacktrace**

> 1 microsoft_phone_ni  Microsoft.Phone.UserData.PhoneDataSharingContext.MapHrToException   0x7669E
>   2 microsoft_phone_ni  Microsoft.Phone.UserData.QueryDataEnumerable_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].EnsureInteropInit    0x54
>   3 microsoft_phone_ni  Microsoft.Phone.UserData.QueryDataEnumerable_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].GetNextBatch 0x30
>   4 microsoft_phone_ni  Microsoft.Phone.UserData.QueryDataEnumerator_1[[System.__Canon,_mscorlib]].MoveNext 0x1A
>   5 microsoft_phone_ni  Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts.GetContacts   0x82
>   6 mscorlib_ni System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context 0x44
>   7 mscorlib_ni System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal   0x90
>   8 mscorlib_ni System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run   0x10
>   9 mscorlib_ni System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem 0x44

What will be the reason for this exception and whats will be the solution ? Please assist me !

Thank you all